# How to resize an Image object in javascript and keep using the modified object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have one problem while doing a little game.

I made a little puzzle game where the user is allowed to play with his own image (after selecting it). The problem is that I want to always use a 600x400 canvas as it fits perfectly on the same page as other elements.

Having to deal with the resize problems, I have to scale my image so it fits in that 600x400 spot. Using the canvas drawImage() method I can do it once, but my problem is that I still need that "resized image" for internal calculations (to divide into pieces and so on).

So I ask you if anyone know any way to do this (resizing my internal Image object and keep using that new "resized object" or any library that allows me to do this).

EDIT: Added some code. The image object declaration is a standard one

```
image = new Image();
image.src="myImage.jpg";
```

Problem is that previous Image can have any random resolution. What I needed is something like (I know I can't do the assignement since drawImage() doesn't return any object, just for illustrating what I need)

```
image_aux = ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, puzzleWidth, puzzleHeight);
```

I need to have something similar to that so in advance I can do any operation with my "custom" resolution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just add

```
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

after the first drawImage() and thing done, no more problems, the url that create that line is the image resized (since are jpg in this case, or bmp if specified with their coordinates)